# Hibernate performance issue: query execution extremely slow

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate

The following hibernate query is being used to fetch a list of ProductCatalogue records, by passing in catId and inventoryId

```
select prodcat from ProductCatalogue prodcat where prodcat.prodSec.prodId=:catId and prodcat.prodPlacedOrder.inventoryId=:inventoryId
```

The tables ProductCatalogue and ProdPlacedOrder are tables with 3 lakh + records. inventoryId is a column in prodOrder table, and prodPlacedOrder extends prodOrder table.

This query on execution takes a lot of time, and the single hibernate query shoots off many complex sql queries.

Any suggestions on what might be the issue and how to modify it such that the query is executed faster?

Comment: have you checked the underlyering SQL (i.e by running it independantly of hibernate?) - what indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: How are you determining that the query shoots off many complex queries? Could it be the following lines that _use_ the result that shoot them off?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson From the show_sql logs. No its this particular query itself

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without more info but try making ProdPlacedOrder as LAZY fetch if you dont need any data from that table.

Also as phatmanace, mentioned - check your indices.

Comment: From what I can see, everything except `prodcat` is already lazy loaded.